# Speed up InnoDB mysql database import

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

i just got a new mysql machine (16gb ram, 4x SAS 15k rpm 300GB drives in RAID10), so quite a fast machine.

I have been importing a few databases with a couple million items each, but it takes quite a long time, longer than it should I think. I'm seeing about 1000 inserts per second, and I believe it should be able to do much more. Also the longer the process runs, the slower it gets.

This is my config, any tips to speed things up, but that doesn't hurt reliability of the data.

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
port=48221
user=mysql
old_passwords=0
max_connections = 1500
table_cache = 1024
max_allowed_packet = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
thread_cache = 8
thread_concurrency = 32
query_cache_size = 0M
query_cache_type = 0
default-storage-engine = innodb
transaction_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
tmp_table_size = 256M
long_query_time = 3
log_slow_queries = 1
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=48M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_io_capacity=500
innodb_read_io_threads=16
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5000M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_thread_concurrency =32

[mysqldump]
quick
single-transaction

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could drop the indexes for the duration of the import, and rebuild them when it's done. You should also try chunking the inserts, searching for the sweet spot between autocommit and all inserts in a single transaction.

Comment: thanks for the tips. but config settings wise, any suggestions?

Comment: That's not my cup of tea, someone else will have to pitch in.